# Converting String to time only?

Tags: android

I'm getting a string from the database and converting it into a time, eg 12:19, and then I'm adding it to the timepicker. The problem is it's taking the time and date and I cant seem to get rid of the date part. My code is below

```
 public static final String TIME_FORMAT = "kk:mm";
    String StartTime = reminder.getString(reminder.getColumnIndexOrThrow(DatabaseStore.START_TIME));

 SimpleDateFormat dateTimeFormat = new SimpleDateFormat(TIME_FORMAT);
    startTime = dateTimeFormat.parse(StartTime); 

    addTimeTopicker.setTime(startTime);
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> and coveting it into time eg 12:19 and then im adding it to the
>   timepicker

You have bad pattern, you can't use kk.

**So you can use these approaches:**

```
public static final String TIME_FORMAT = "h:mm";
Result: 12:01 [h is hour in AM / PM (1-12)]

public static final String TIME_FORMAT = "k:mm";
Result: 12:01 [k is hour in day (1-24)]
```

Have look at [SimpleDateFormat patterns](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/1.4.2/docs/api/java/text/SimpleDateFormat.html)

Answer (score 0):

You're not telling the date formatter to use your specific format:

```
Date d = new Date(timeString);
SimpleDateFormat sdf = new SimpleDateFormat("hh:mm aa");
String newtimeString = sdf.format(d);
```

That would return, for example: 12:19 PM

Comment: sorry i forgot a line i think i was telling it i was using   SimpleDateFormat dateTimeFormat = new SimpleDateFormat(TIME_FORMAT);

Comment: Well that would definitely be your problem :P

Comment: but when i do this i get back like default time of the system, like jan 01 12.30 GMT 1970 for some reason any idea problem something stupid i did

Comment: If you're getting "Jan 01 12.30 GMT 1970," then it's not just an issue with the date format. It's because you're passing 0 to the date object which is instantiated with milliseconds since 1970. And as hawaii.five-0 said, you can't use kk and instead should use what I listed above, as it will just revert back to the default format which is what you're seeing.

Comment: I changed it to what ye said above use hh:mm, it gets the stuff from the database eg it gets 11:11(in that format) from a string in the database but when i use dateformat ( startTime = dateTimeFormat.parse(StartTimeUpdate);  ) when i check whats in startTime it goes back to default time eg Jan 01 12.30 GMT 1970

Comment: It seems like you're trying to parse a date that's not a 'real date' and the problem is actually how you're storing the data in your DB, not just how you're trying to parse it. You should read up on the Date object http://developer.android.com/reference/java/util/Date.html and find the correct constructor that matches how you're saving your date info. I recommend saving the dates in your DB in the form of milliseconds then parsing that using the SimpleDateFormat I posted above.